Workmanager package issue in Flutter
workmanager package has issues with ios. How can I solve this? Workmanager package version: 0.5.2:
AppDelegate.swift file:
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import workmanager
Podfile:
platform :ios, '13.0'
I followed the ios setup but still got errors saying **Compiling for iOS 12.0, but module 'workmanager' has a minimum deployment target of iOS, **
I tried to run ios on my physical ios device and it is for running the code in the background periodically.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
